# Overlapping Event for multiple classes

Tags: unreal-engine4

We're working on a small Unreal Engine game. For this purpose, I've need the possibility to check for overlapping events of the character with multiple blueprints (obstacles etc.). The problem is I haven't found a possibility yet to check an overlapping event for multiple classes (let's say BPObstacle1, BPObstacle2 and so on) - the only thing I can achieve is to proof if the character overlaps with one specific class. In other words, i need some kind of a "class switcher" or "class dispatcher" to proof for multiple classes.

Now someone could ask, why not simply add an overlap event to the obstacles instead of the character? This is because the liftetime of the object (BPObstacles) need to be longer. For example, I need to destroy an actor (BPObstacle) before a sound starts to play. None of the blocks are executed after an "Destroy actor" command, so you can't play a sound after the actor (BPObstacle) was destroyed.

The temporary workaround for me is to duplicate the capsule component of the character, this gives me the possibility to add one overlapping event for each capsule (and so for a collision with each different obstacle). This is something most of the people needed I think, but I haven't found a better way to achieve this. Would be nice if someone has a tip for me.

Below I've added a code snippet of how an overlapping event looks like (for BpObstacle1). Instead of checking for one class, I need to check for a bunch of classes.

[image: Overlapping Event in Unreal Engine 4 for one specific class]

Answer (score 0):

I've found it out by myself. The way I do this now is to create an array of all obstacles (type of array is class->actor). Then I proof when the overlapping event is triggered if the overlapping class is contained in the obstacles array. If so, do something you want to do (in my case set a variable). And here's the corresponding blueprint code:

[image: Overlapping event for multiple blueprint classes]